# A Fredholm equation with non-separable kernel

Tags: integration, integral-operators

I'm trying to solve this form of Fredholm equation:

$$
g(v)=f_1(v)+\int\limits_{0}^{v_\mathrm{th}} g(v_s)\frac{e^{-\tfrac{\big[(v-v_\mathrm{init})-(1-v_\mathrm{leak})(v_s-v_\mathrm{init})\big]^2}{2v_\mathrm{step}^2}}+e^{-\tfrac{\big[(v+v_\mathrm{init})+(1-v_\mathrm{leak})(v_s-v_\mathrm{init})\big]^2}{2v_\mathrm{step}^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}v_\mathrm{step}}\mathrm{d} v_s,
$$
where,

- $v_\mathrm{init}$, $v_\mathit{th}$, $v_\mathrm{step}$, $v_\mathrm{leak}$ are constant and
- $f_1$ has the following form:
  $$
  f_1(v)=\frac{e^{-\tfrac{(v-v_\mathrm{init})^2}{2v_\mathrm{step}^2}}+e^{-\tfrac{(v+v_\mathrm{init})^2}{2v_\mathrm{step}^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}v_\mathrm{step}}
  $$

Are there any methods or theorems that can solve this problem?

Since I'm freshman in university, it's very challenging for me. But I really want to untangle this problem.

Can you help me to solve this kind of equation or let me know what theory I should study?

I would be grateful if you could just give me directions, so I can know where to start studying. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Where is the equation?

Comment: I signed up yesterday, and I think I was restricted to upload figures. Thank you for editing my question.

Comment: Are you sure the second exponential term is correct in the kernel? Looks there is no connection between kernel and your f1 function

Comment: Oh, I think the editor made a mistake by changing the picture to an expression. I edited second term in kernel, so that K(v,vinit)=f1(v).